# ¿porque no me cargan archivos como jquery y waypoints si ya los enlace con scripts?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1">
    <title>Nuno - Responsive Bootstrap Theme</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-5.7.2-web/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/arrow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fixed.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/waypoints.css">
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
    <!-- Start Home Section -->
    <div id="home">
    <!-- Start Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/nuno.png"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
          <span class="custom-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#home" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#features" class="nav-link">FEATURES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">PRICING</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#team" class="nav-link">TEAM</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#skills" class="nav-link">SKILLS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#clients" class="nav-link">CLIENTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Start of the Landing Page Image -->
    <div class="landing">
      <div class="home-wrap">
        <div class="home-inner">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caption center-block text-center">
      <div class="os-animation" data-animation="bounceInUp" data-delay="0.6s">
        <h1>Welcome to Nuno</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="os-animation" data-animation="bounceInUp" data-delay="0.8s">
        <h3>Animated Bootstrap Theme</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="os-animation" data-animation="bounceInUp" data-delay="1s">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="#features">Get Started</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Start Features Section -->
    <div id="features" class="offset">

    </div>
    <!-- Start Portfolio Section -->
    <div id="portfolio" class="offset">

    </div>
    <!-- Start Pricing Section -->
    <div id="pricing" class="offset">

    </div>
    <!-- Start Team Section -->
    <div id="team" class="offset">

    </div>
    <!-- Start Skills Section -->
    <div id="skills" class="offset">

    </div>
    <!-- Start Clients Section -->
    <div id="clients" class="offset">

    </div>
    <!-- Start Contact Section -->
    <div id="contact" class="offset">

    </div>
    <!-- Script Source Files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fontawesome-free-5.7.2-web/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La consola te esta diciendo perfectamente que no puede cargar esa librería porque no encuentra el archivo...

Comment: pero si estan dentro de mi carpeta js no se cual sera el problema

Comment: Puedes mostrar una captura del directorio donde tienes los archivos `.js`? El error dice que no encuentra el archivo `jquery.waypoints.js`

Comment: ya añadi una imagen solo mira @IvanS95

Comment: noooo en realidad estoy incluyendo ambos, debo incluir los dos porque son diferentes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate bien en los archivos que estas incluyendo, uno de ellos lleva el nombre: `jquery.waypoints.js`; sin embargo el archivo que se encuentra en tu directorio es `jquery.waypoints.min.js`; si modificas esto en tu HTML deberia funcionar correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!-- Script Source Files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fontawesome-free-5.7.2-web/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.waypoints.js"></script> <!--Este archivo no existe -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.js"></script>

<!-- Script Source Files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fontawesome-free-5.7.2-web/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script> <!--Agregale el .min  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
```

Comment: aah ya entendi, gracias si tenias razon!!